# Class usage inside class static initialization block

Tags: java, class, static

Probably it is discussed somewhere but I failed to find it.

I need to load class properties (`java.util.Properties`) inside class static initialization block. This is to make possible to access some class general options even without its objects creation. To do so I need appropriate `Class` object. But of course access to such Class object fails on `null` object. Something like this.

```
Class Name {

    private static Properties properties;

    static {
        Name.properties = new Properties();
        Name.properties.load(Name.class.getResourceAsStream("Name.properties"));
    }

}
```

Any idea how to handle this situation?

UPDATE:
It was resource name (should be "/Name.properties" for my case). Everything else was OK.
+1 for all meaningful answers from me and ... don't forget to check operations one by one :-).

Comment: Declare `properties` static too.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually done in original code, typo. Corrected.

Comment: I hope following will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044855/load-java-properties-inside-static-intializer-block

Comment: If you're setting Name.properties to a new Properties object, the only thing that could be null is the value returned by `getResourceAsStream`.  Make sure Name.properties is in the same directory as Name.class in your .jar file.

Comment: Just found the same thing.

Comment: This code looks like you want to make the `properties` field `final` too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I made in final code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`properties` field must be `static`. And before `load` you need to initialize static variable with `proeprties = new Properties()` after that you can invoke `load`

Answer (score 1):

Declare properties as static and initialize

```
static Properties properties;
```

or

```
static Properties properties = new Properties();
```

and static block should be

```
static {
    try {
        properties = new Properties(); //if you have not initialize it already
        Name.properties.load(Name.class.getResourceAsStream("Name.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e); //or some message in constructor
    }
}
```

You need to catch IOException while loading properties file

Comment: `printStackTrace` is one of the worst ways to handle the exception, unless Roman actually doesn't care if the properties file was loaded.  The correct course of action is `throw new RuntimeException(e);`.

Comment: I know its just that I wanted to be specific to question, the OP needs to handle exceptions properly. I won't be writing entire code for him :)

Comment: An `ExceptionInInitializerError` would be even better IMHO: "Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable."

Comment: @GyroGearless yes ExceptionInInitializerError would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Final code based on all suggestions is like this:

```
Class Name {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            InputStream stream = Name.class.getResourceAsStream("/Name.properties");
            if (stream == null) {
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Failed to open properties stream.");
            }
            Name.properties.load(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Failed to load properties.");
        }
    }
}
```